# UI of the application I built Opens a window but doesn't display any UI elements(on other mac's not my own, it works on mine)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I created an `application with a UI using swift for mac with xcode`. I built the application to run on `mac 10.10` and above but when I built it to run and ran it on another mac which had `os 10.10.5` the application opened a window but, `the window was much smaller than the window size I set and it doesn't display any of the UI elements either`.

This application when run on my mac which runs on `os 10.13` works perfectly but doesn't on others what am i doing wrong or how can I figure out what is going wrong.

someone on reddit suggested `notarising` the application may fix it but if that doesn't work is there anything else that I can do to fix this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're doing the UI in swift, not using SwiftUI, right?  How are you building the UI? (Storyboards, code, XIBs, a UI framework) What features are you using? Are you sure all those features and the selected options are available in 10.10?  I'd start by checking if another 10.13 machine is able to run the binary you make, that would verify that it's an OS problem and not a binary problem.  If it doesn't run on another 10.13 machine, then you may have a Resource inclusion issue or a conditional link error. Lack of Notarization shouldn't cause this problem, App would fail 2 launch

Comment: Nope i'm not using Swift UI. i'm using Storyboards and yes the reasons i set it to 10.10 is because that version is the last version with Storyboard support. I think it might be a rendering issue since there's some code that fetches data which still seems to run. it's only the UI elements that aren't being displayed. I did my best to make sure that I use UI elements that are supported by OS 10.10 so maybe I slipped up there.